# Android: Picasso - URLS Improperly Populating ImageViews

Tags: java, android, for-loop, imageview, picasso

I'm attempting to populate a series of ImageViews using Picasso - however for some reason - only the first image is populated. Can anyone tell why this might be happening? I've looked this over many times and I cannot seem to spot the issue in this for loop:

### DEBUGGING  / LOGGING:

```
09-26 23:10:58.445: I/System.out(14978): WTF :https://i.ytimg.com/vi/oSYctdFjFSw/default.jpg
09-26 23:10:58.456: I/System.out(14978): WTF : https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DyFE4IEjX4I/default.jpg
09-26 23:10:58.466: I/System.out(14978): WTF : https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6XCU_Wv0ekA/default.jpg
09-26 23:10:58.475: I/System.out(14978): WTF : https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5U1ndFiYLh4/default.jpg
09-26 23:10:58.483: I/System.out(14978): WTF : https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6gLscCEiSXE/default.jpg
```

### SOURCE:

```
    ImageView imageItem1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        // Create new ImageView
        imageItem1 = new ImageView(this);

        // Set the shadow background
        imageItem1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shadow);
        String[] separated = result.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");
        String scrubbedURL = separated[j].toString();
        Picasso.with(this).load(scrubbedURL).into(imageItem1);
        System.out.println("WTF :" + scrubbedURL);
        // Set the size of the image view to the previously computed value
        imageItem1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                imageWidth, imageWidth));

        // / Add image view to the carousel container
        mCarouselContainer1.addView(imageItem1);
        ++j;
    }
```

### Result:

[image]

Any suggestions / comments / insights are appreciated... I'm stumped.

Comment: try   String scrubbedURL = separated[j].trim();

Comment: Dude! You fixed it... I can't believe it was something as simple as the trailing white space... (You can go ahead and leave your solution as an answer if you'd like - that was super helpful for me and might be for someone else in the future!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
ImageView imageItem1;
String[] separated = result.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    // Create new ImageView
    imageItem1 = new ImageView(this);

    // Set the shadow background
    imageItem1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shadow);

    String scrubbedURL = separated[j].trim();
    ...
    ++j;
}
```